# windows form how to check in database if user already exist?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I want to create a simple form where I want to validate to show message if same users exists.

The function usernamecheck() checks for validation and displays error if same user exists but when I click submit button it still submits same user.

```
 private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
  con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LFC;Initial Catalog=contactmgmt;Integrated Security=True";
  con.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cntc_employee (emp_f_name,emp_l_name,emp_alias,emp_contact_no,emp_address,emp_company,emp_bdate) VALUES(@fname,@lname,@alias,@contact,@address,@company,@bdate)";
  cmd.Connection = con;

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", textBox1.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", textBox2.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alias", textBox3.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", textBox4.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox5.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", textBox6.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bdate", textBox7.Text.ToString());

  UserNameCheck();

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
  MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Succesfully");
}

public void UserNameCheck()
{

  string constring = "Data Source=LFC;Initial Catalog=contactmgmt;Integrated Security=True";
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from cntc_employee where emp_alias= @alias", con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alias", this.textBox3.Text);
  con.Open();
  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    if (dr.HasRows == true)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Alias "+ dr[1].ToString() +" Already exist");
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `UserNameCheck` works exactly as you want? Did you debug your code? And use `using statement` to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`

Comment: can u show us `usernamecheck()` function code?

Comment: yes it works i think i am doing something wrong on the last 3 line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You are Inserting the record always without check wether user exist or not.

**Solution :**
You need to return the boolean value from the `UserNameCheck()` function.

retrun `true` if username exist.
return `false` if username doesnot exist.

then execute the `Insert Query` if and only if  `UserNameCheck` function returns `false`

Try This:

Chnage the `UserNameCheck()` function code as below to return the `boolean` value.

```
public bool UserNameCheck()
{        
    string constring = "Data Source=LFC;Initial Catalog=contactmgmt;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from cntc_employee where emp_alias= @alias", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alias", this.textBox3.Text);
    con.Open();
    int TotalRows = 0;
    TotalRows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    if(TotalRows > 0)
    {            
           MessageBox.Show("Alias "+ dr[1].ToString() +" Already exist");
           return true;
    }
    else
    {
           return false;
    }
}
```

Now Change the `Submit` function code to verify the `UserNameCheck()` return value, proceed to the insertion only if the `UserNameCheck()` function returns `false`(when user does not exist)

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!UserNameCheck())
   {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LFC;Initial Catalog=contactmgmt;Integrated Security=True";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cntc_employee (emp_f_name,emp_l_name,emp_alias,emp_contact_no,emp_address,emp_company,emp_bdate) VALUES(@fname,@lname,@alias,@contact,@address,@company,@bdate)";
    cmd.Connection = con;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alias", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", textBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", textBox6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bdate", textBox7.Text.ToString());



    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Succesfully");
 }
}
```

Comment: #Sudhakar Tillapudi: how to check validation for many other  textboxes  if it is empty  or not

Comment: @skates008: feilds by you mean database table feilds? if yes then you need to use `IS NULL` in `where` clause. Try This -> `select * from mytable where address is NULL`

Answer (score 2):

First fire a select query that checks whether a user exists or not. If not then fire insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a `select count` by `name` for the user first, and if the `counter` is bigger than `0` make the `insert`